# Equivalent fr.obeo.acceleo.gen.module extension in Acceleo 3

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, acceleo

I'm using Acceleo 3 and desired to export my project as a plugin.
I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.acceleo.org/pages/exporting-a-generator-as-plugin/en).

Unfortunately, Acceleo 3 doesn't include `fr.obeo.acceleo.gen.module`. Is there any equivalent module in Acceleo 3?